# Why is vercel host throwing an error on code that works ok on localhost?

Tags: typescript, next.js, entity, vercel

This code works fine on localhost. It breaks on the vercel host with a cyclic dependency error message.

I'm not seeing anything here that would cause that.

The code adds a record - ExhibitPaintingDetail - that points to two other records - Exhibit and Painting. One ExhibitPaintingDetail can point to only one unique combination of Exibit and Painting. Each Painting can be targeted by any number of ExhibitPaintingDetails. Each Exhibit can be targeted by any number of ExhibitPaintingDetails.

Code:

```
import { AppDataSource } from "../../data-source";
import { Painting } from "../../entity/Painting";
import { Exhibit } from "../../entity/Exhibit";
import { ExhibitPaintingDetail } from "../../entity/ExhibitPaintingDetail";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import test from "../../app/test/page";

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const paintingid =
      typeof req.query["paintingid"] === "string"
        ? Number.parseInt(req.query["paintingid"])
        : undefined;
    const exhibitid =
      typeof req.query["exhibitid"] === "string"
        ? Number.parseInt(req.query["exhibitid"])
        : undefined;

    // console.log("paintingid: ", paintingid);
    // console.log("exhibitid: ", exhibitid);

    try {
      if (!AppDataSource.isInitialized) {
        await AppDataSource.initialize();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }

    const paintingRepository = await AppDataSource.getRepository(Painting);
    const exhibitRepository = await AppDataSource.getRepository(Exhibit);
    const exhibitPaintingDetailRepository = await AppDataSource.getRepository(
      ExhibitPaintingDetail
    );

    if (paintingid !== undefined && exhibitid !== undefined) {
      const painting = await paintingRepository.findOne({
        where: { id: paintingid },
      });
      const exhibit = await exhibitRepository.findOne({
        where: { id: exhibitid },
      });

      const exhibitPaintingDetail = new ExhibitPaintingDetail();
      try {
        exhibitPaintingDetail.exhibit = exhibit;
        exhibitPaintingDetail.painting = painting;
        // exhibitPaintingDetail.exhibit.id = exhibitid;
        // exhibitPaintingDetail.painting.id = paintingid;
        // try {
        //console.log("exhibitPaintingDetail: ", exhibitPaintingDetail);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }

      // try {
      const result = await exhibitPaintingDetailRepository.save(
        exhibitPaintingDetail
      );
      // test save
      console.log("result: ", result);
      //
      res
        .status(200)
        .json({ success: true, redirectUrl: `/painting?id=${paintingid}` });
      // } catch (e) {
      //   //console.log(e);

      //   return res.status(400).send({ success: false, error: e });
      // }
    }
  } else {
    res.status(405).send({ error: "Method Not Allowed" });
  }
}
```

Entities:

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  JoinColumn,
  ManyToOne,
} from "typeorm";
import { Exhibit } from "./Exhibit";
import { Painting } from "./Painting";

@Entity("exhibitpaintingdetail")
export class ExhibitPaintingDetail {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id?: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  exhibitpaintingid: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  submissiondate: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  exhibitpaintingprice: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  status: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  outcome: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  note: string;

  // @Column()
  // exhibitid: number;

  // @Column()
  // paintingid: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Exhibit, (exhibit) => exhibit.exhibitPaintingDetails)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "exhibitid" })
  exhibit: any;

  @ManyToOne(() => Painting, (painting) => painting.exhibitPaintingDetails)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "paintingid" })
  painting: any;
}

import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  ManyToOne,
  //ManyToMany,
  //OneToOne,
  //JoinTable,
  OneToMany,
  JoinColumn,
  //Relation,
} from "typeorm";
//import * as typeorm from "typeorm";
import { Gallery } from "./Gallery";
//import { Painting } from "./Painting";
import { ExhibitPaintingDetail } from "./ExhibitPaintingDetail";

@Entity("exhibit")
export class Exhibit {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id?: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  description: string;

  @Column({ default: true })
  isEnabled?: boolean;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  startDate: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  endDate: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  dropOffDate: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  pickUpDate: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  galleryId: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  note: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  decisionDate?: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  website: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Gallery, (gallery) => gallery.exhibits, {})
  @JoinColumn({ name: "galleryId" })
  gallery: Gallery;

  @OneToMany(
    () => ExhibitPaintingDetail,
    (exhibitPaintingDetail) => exhibitPaintingDetail.exhibit
  )
  exhibitPaintingDetails: ExhibitPaintingDetail[];
}

import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  ManyToMany,
  JoinTable,
  OneToMany,
} from "typeorm";
import { Exhibit } from "./Exhibit";
import { Person } from "./Person";
import { ExhibitPaintingDetail } from "./ExhibitPaintingDetail";
import { Tag } from "./Tag";
import { dateTimeRangeList } from "aws-sdk/clients/health";

@Entity("painting")
export class Painting {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Column()
  picture: string;

  @Column()
  description: string;

  @Column("int")
  artistId: number;

  @Column("int")
  month: number;

  @Column()
  year: number;

  @Column()
  media: string;

  @Column()
  price: number;

  @Column()
  width: number;

  @Column()
  height: number;

  @Column()
  sold: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  depth: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  note: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  api_id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  permalink: string;

  @Column("timestamp without time zone", { nullable: true })
  timestamp: Date;

  @OneToMany(
    () => ExhibitPaintingDetail,
    (exhibitPaintingDetail) => exhibitPaintingDetail.painting
  )
  exhibitPaintingDetails: ExhibitPaintingDetail[];

  @ManyToMany(() => Tag, (tag) => tag.paintings)
  @JoinTable({
    name: "tagpaintings", // name of the join table
    joinColumn: {
      name: "paintingid", // name of the column in the join table that references the Painting entity
      referencedColumnName: "id", // name of the id column in the Painting entity
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      name: "tagid", // name of the column in the join table that references the Tag entity
      referencedColumnName: "id", // name of the id column in the Tag entity
    },
  })
  tags: Tag[];
}
```

Error from Vercel host:

```
query: START TRANSACTION
query: ROLLBACK
TypeORMError: Cyclic dependency: "y"
    at visit (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:147:23)
    at visit (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:164:21)
    at SubjectTopoligicalSorter.toposort (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:143:17)
    at SubjectTopoligicalSorter.sort (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:53:45)
    at SubjectExecutor.execute (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectExecutor.js:91:108)
    at EntityPersistExecutor.execute (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/EntityPersistExecutor.js:140:36)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async l (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/addpaintingtoexhibitw2params.js:1:12275)
 ⨯ TypeORMError: Cyclic dependency: "y"
    at visit (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:147:23)
    at visit (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:164:21)
    at SubjectTopoligicalSorter.toposort (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:143:17)
    at SubjectTopoligicalSorter.sort (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:53:45)
    at SubjectExecutor.execute (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectExecutor.js:91:108)
    at EntityPersistExecutor.execute (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/EntityPersistExecutor.js:140:36)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async l (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/addpaintingtoexhibitw2params.js:1:12275)
TypeORMError: Cyclic dependency: "y"
    at visit (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:147:23)
    at visit (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:164:21)
    at SubjectTopoligicalSorter.toposort (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:143:17)
    at SubjectTopoligicalSorter.sort (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:53:45)
    at SubjectExecutor.execute (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectExecutor.js:91:108)
    at EntityPersistExecutor.execute (/var/task/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/EntityPersistExecutor.js:140:36)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async l (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/addpaintingtoexhibitw2params.js:1:12275)
Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

Comment: I don't know `typeorm` but this error is typical for ORM when mapping goes around between entities. I don't see it in your code but maybe there are something special with typeorm and bidirectional mapping that I'm not aware of or something through `Gallery`. As for why it only fails on Vercel, I guess you might not have data or didn't restart the server locally after a breaking change.

Comment: Vercel is refreshed with every code change.

Comment: This is the Gallery entity:```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToMany } from "typeorm";
import { Exhibit } from "./Exhibit";
import { join } from "path";

@Entity("gallery")
export class Gallery {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ default: "empty name" })
  name: string;

  @Column({ default: "empty description" })
  description: string;

  @Column({ default: false })
  isEnabled: boolean;

  @OneToMany(() => Exhibit, (exhibit) => exhibit.gallery)
  exhibits: Exhibit[];
}```

Comment: This is the client-side form code that invokes the api method:  
  
  fetch(
      `/api/addpaintingtoexhibitw2params?paintingid=${paintingId}&exhibitid=${key}`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          paintingId: paintingId,
          exhibitId: key,
        }),
      }
    )

Comment: I made this change to the Gallery entity and refactored the code where necessary, 
changing from exhibit.gallery to exhibit.__gallery__ or gallery.__exhibit(s)__: 

  @OneToMany(() => Exhibit, (exhibit) => exhibit.gallery)
  exhibits: Promise<Exhibit[]>; 

The app succeeds with updates and deletions elsewhere. this is the only data change problem that succeeds on localhost and fails on vercel.